# AngularJS input filed checkbox ng-click not firing method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to call function in toggle switch by ng-click, but the **customerActiveDeactive** funtion is not fire.

```
<a title="Active/ Deactivate" >
   <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" ng-init="status=True" ng-model="status" ng-name="status" ng-checked="{{ customer.status|lower }}" ng-click="customerActiveDeactive({{ customer.id }})" />
</a>

$scope.customerActiveDeactive = function(id) {
        console.log("method call");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, since customer id your django variable, Simply change this line :

```
ng-click="customerActiveDeactive({{ customer.id }})"
```

to

```
ng-click="customerActiveDeactive('{{ customer.id }}')"
```

Comment: {{ customer.id }} is my django variable

Comment: is  customer.id  variable is set as a scope variable?

Comment: {{ customer.id }} send to as parameter of customerActiveDeactive(id. isn't it?

Comment: @ShafikurRahmanShaon i have updated my answer please try with this change. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing variable as a argument in wrong way:
Do it like this:

```
<a title="Active/ Deactivate" >
       <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" ng-init="status=True" ng-model="status" ng-name="status" ng-checked="{{ customer.status|lower }}" ng-click="customerActiveDeactive(customer.id )" />
    </a>

    $scope.customerActiveDeactive = function(id) {
            console.log("method call");
    }
```

Comment: {{ customer.id }} is my django variable

Comment: then store this variable in $scope.var="value" and then you can use var in html